# Laravel: form with axios not saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, post, axios

I'm writing an User Edit functionality with `vue.js` front-end.

The axios part:

```
sendUserData(){
                axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name,
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                        }
                    }
                ).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if(response.data == 'success'){
                        this.$emit('userSaveSuccess')
                    } else {
                        this.$emit('userSaveError')
                    }
                });
```

The output is `success`, but in the Database there isn't any changes. I tried with Postman too, and that time the data is changed, so the controller is working properly. What's the matter with this part?

**Edit:**

My controller method:

```
public function saveUser($name = '', $email = '', $password = ''){

    $id = request('data.id', 0);
    $name = request('data.name', $name);
    $email = request('data.email', $email);
    $password = request('data.pswrd', $password);

    Log::info(request());

    if($id == 0){
        $saveUser = new User;
    } else {
        $saveUser = User::find($id);
        if($name == ''){
            $name = $saveUser -> name;
        }
        if($email == ''){
            $email = $saveUser -> email;
        }
    }
    $saveUser -> name = $name;
    $saveUser -> email = $email;
    if($password != ''){
        $saveUser -> password = bcrypt($password);
    }
    if($saveUser->save()){
        return 'success';
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data needs to be sent within the `data` property.

```js
axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
        // don't forget the data property
        data: {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }
    }, 
    // ...
```

It would probably be a good idea to set up some validation in your controller too, as that would have made it apparent you weren't receiving the appropriate data.

**EDIT:** Thank you for posting the controller method.

You don't need to use `data.*` when retrieving the request data in the controller.  This is simply where they go in axios to pass them as request variables.  Also, the `pswrd` parameter in your controller does not match `password` which you are sending with axios.

```php
public function saveUser($name = '', $email = '', $password = ''){

    // get your parameters from the request helper
    // you don't need to use data.* here
    $id = request('id', 0);
    $name = request('name', $name);
    $email = request('email', $email);
    $password = request('password', $password);  // this is not 'pswrd'


    // ...


    // you should consider switching to the Hash facade to allow
    // hashing to be configured within `/config/hashing.php`
    if ($password != ''){
        $saveUser->password = Hash::make($password);
    }


    // ...
}
```

As a final note, it's important to know that Laravel only updates an entry if the data has changed. If you send the same values, there will be no change. Since your method involves retrieving the existing name and email when those request values are empty, this might explain why it appears that nothing is saving in the database.

To force an update of the timestamps without any changes, you would need to call the `->touch()` method on the model.

Comment: Tried it, but Laravel still not saving

Comment: Assuming you already ran `npm run dev` or the equivalent after making the changes, then you are going to need to provide your controller method.  Then we can figure out how you are receiving a `success` response with no database changes.  The only other thing I can see from your post is the the missing `}` at the end of the `sendUserData()` method, but I imagine it just got chopped off in the copy/paste.

Comment: I placed my controller method in the question. Yes the missing `}` is a chop from copy/paste.

Comment: I updated the answer yesterday, but I forgot to post a comment letting you know.  Sorry for the late notice.  I hope the updates help.